# I want to use a button declared in a bottomsheetdialog, and I want to set the onClicklistener in the parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-dialogfragment

My Button is present in this dialog:

```
public class VerifyOrderDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    ImageButton bt_downarrow;
    public  Button bt_pick;
}
```

This BottomSheetDialogFragment is called on an button click present in an adapter of this fragment

```
public class DeliveryOrderAssignedFragment extends Fragment implements MyClickListener {
    private RecyclerView assignedOrdersList;
    private LinearLayout erLayout,successLayout;
    private ContainerActivity activity;
    private ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This fragment is a child of this fragment and I want to implement the onClick of bt_pick here..

```
public class DeliveryFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, VerifyOrderDialog.VerfyOrderDialogCallback {
    private ContainerActivity activity;
    private MyPagingHandlerViewPager pager;
    private TabLayout tabs;
    private LinearLayout dataLayout,errorLayout;
    private DeliveryOrderAssignedFragment assignFragment;
    private VerifyOrderDialog verifyOrderDialog;
}

`
```

Comment: Using [Event Buss](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) makes it easy to communicate between fragments in this case. If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

handle click events on onCreateView() method of the fragment in which the button is present